# Genesys Pulse - Adding a Custom Statistic to a Template

Tags: pulse, genesys

I'm trying to add a custom Statistic to Pulse Web. This statistic is currently used in CCpulse and I'm trying to replicate it in Pulse Web. From the documentation it seems like I need the Main Mask, Subject and Category but it's never explained how they come into play.

Is there a way for me to pull this statistic via Formula or the Statistic Type field? I tried using the same Statistic Type name I saw in CCPulse but this gave me an ERROR value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom formula statistics in the stat server options tab with Category, Objects, Expression, Subject, MainMask, etc. as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/RTME/latest/User/Formula).